# How can I continue "for-loop" even after an error?

Tags: python-3.x, csv, for-loop, try-catch, zendesk

I need some help. I need my code to continue the "for" after error, just show the ticket with an error and skip to the next one without stopping the script.

```
from zenpy.lib.api_objects import CustomField
from zenpy import Zenpy
import csv, sys

creds = {
    'email' : 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
    'token' : 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
    'subdomain': 'xxxxxxxxxxx'
}

zenpy_client = Zenpy(**creds)

arquivo = '/Users/IDS.csv'
with open(arquivo, 'rt', encoding='utf8') as ficheiro:
    leitor = csv.reader(ficheiro)
    try:
        contador = 0
        for linha in leitor:
            
            if contador != 0:
                ticket = zenpy_client.tickets(id=linha[0])
                ticket.custom_fields.append(CustomField(id=1900002490207, value=linha[1]))
                zenpy_client.tickets.update(ticket)
                print ('O Ticket = ', linha[0], 'Teve o Este Valor Inserido = ', linha[1])
            contador = contador + 1
    except csv.Error as e:
        print('ficheiro %s, linha %d: %s' % (arquivo, leitor.line_num, e))
```

Comment: move the `try` block inside the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Put the try-except in the for loop

```
for linha in leitor:
        try:
            if contador != 0:
                ticket = zenpy_client.tickets(id=linha[0])
                ticket.custom_fields.append(CustomField(id=1900002490207, value=linha[1]))
                zenpy_client.tickets.update(ticket)
                print ('O Ticket = ', linha[0], 'Teve o Este Valor Inserido = ', linha[1])
            contador = contador + 1
        except csv.Error as e:
            print('ficheiro %s, linha %d: %s' % (arquivo, leitor.line_num, e))
```

To cover even more errors, you could replace the `csv.Error` with `Exception`